# " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' " error while importing tensorflow in python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working on image classification. I installed tensorflow using "pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" command which I got in stackoverflow and after successful installation I could not import it in python IDLE and PyCharm also.

Only one error occured 
`ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'`

I tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) but it didn't work.

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Found the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784942/no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal-error) resolved. Please follow this to solve the error.