# No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am trying to run the following code:

```
import tensorflow
from imageai.Prediction.Custom import ModelTraining

model_trainer = ModelTraining()
model_trainer.setModelTypeAsResNet()
model_trainer.setDataDirectory("idenprof")
model_trainer.trainModel(num_objects=10, num_experiments=200, enhance_data=True, batch_size=32, show_network_summary=True)
```

But I am getting the following error. It says No module name `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal`. I tried importing tensorflow as well. But the problem still persists. How do I fix this? I am new to Python, so I might have missed something silly.

```
F:\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:/Python/firstTraining.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\gautham.d\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/firstTraining.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imageai.Prediction.Custom import ModelTraining
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\imageai\Prediction\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\gautham.d\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How did you install Tensorflow, pip?

Comment: Also make sure the version is right. Especially cuda and cudnn in you have them.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like some tensorflow installation problem. Remove your python and tensorflow completely by uninstalling. THen install again following recommended ways for installing.

For [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

For [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3)